# Determine iphone's approximate location

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, geolocation, gps

Any way to know user's approximate geolocation using public API only and without the user's interference?

I know the CLLocationManager can monitor only significant location changes,which as far as I understand - cell tower changes, but does that require location services to be turned on also?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CLLocationManager` will give you the location based on GPS and Cell Tower. Also it's the only class that allows you the get the users location.

But the user has to approve the use of the location for your app.

And Yes if the user turned of the location service `CLLocationManager` will not work.